PS4 controller teloperation not working for TurtleBot and Ignition Gazebo
I am facing issues with teleoperating my TurtleBot 3 in the real world and my virtual robot in Ignition Gazebo. I have a PS4 DualShock controller connected via Bluetooth to my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS 2 Humble. I have confirmed that the laptop receives inputs from the controller using the evtest command.
I am following this tutorial on how to perform joystick teleoperation in ROS2. However, the robot in Ignition Gazebo is not responding to my commands. When I press the buttons on my controller, the following messages pop up on the terminal:
[spawner-8] [WARN] [1735630989.249140222] [spawner_diff_cont]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1735630989.250194490] [spawner_diff_cont]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...

I do see that the joystick is publishing to the /joy and /cmd_vel topics when I echo them, but it is strange why Gazebo is not working.
Likewise, for my TurtleBot 3, only the R1 button works. This means I can only drive my TurtleBot straight forward since my joystick also doesn't work.
Can anyone help offer any suggestions or advice on how to resolve these issues? Thanks in advance.
